Collecting user activity securly before login in application
Collect events for analytics securely
I am collecting data from my application for tracking the click and screen events. Every time screen or click is called from the mobile application a python api will be called where data will sent to the python api for the respective click and screen events.
Now the possiblity of hitting the python api with random hits is high so a secret key is maintained and sent in the request from the mobile (this key is static). This static key will be sent in the sync after login according the existing application flow.
I need to track events registration or app installations before login where the static secret key won't be sent.
Is there any other approach and how this is done gloabally in cases of tracking analytics data of an application
need to know other approaches without JWT token kind of things

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
